# Shift+3 returns £ sign instead of # sign

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, mac-pro, language

When I press Shift+3 on my Mac, it returns £ sign instead of # sign. How can I fix it? Any ideas?
Input source - British - PC

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean by "fix it". It's not broken, shift/3 is £ on a UK keyboard. opt/3 is #. US keyboards are the other way round.

Comment: @Tetsujin British PC does NOT have # at opt/3.  It’s over at the right edge of the keyboard.

Comment: @Ilya as Tom has pointed out you said British PC keyboard - I answered assuming Apple British keyboard - Is it an Apple or a PC/Windows keyboard ?

Comment: Oh, for some reason I never spotted 'PC' :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The keyboard is working as designed for Apple.

If you want to use the keyboard as normal the # is given by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>

I found this annoying as well and the way I get round it is to change the input source to Australian the only difference is that <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> is now # and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> is £

Input Source setting is System Preferences->Keyboard->Input Source By default this will just show the UK keyboard to see more hit the + at the bottom of the list and add Australian

This is the answer I gave in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3977314/151019) and I think is a duplicate here as well but I could not find the original.

Comment: He said he has a British PC layout.  On that # is NOT at alt-3.  It is over at the right edge of the keyboard.  It is the British layout which has # at alt-3.

Comment: @TomGewecke  A good point but OP as also accepted answer so might just be confused

Comment: Yes, perhaps he was mistaken about British-PC being his “input source”, and it was really British.  Some users think their active keyboard is what they happen to have selected in system prefs/keyboard/input sources, when in fact it is the “flag” menu that determines this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the British PC layout, the # sign is found over at the right edge of the keyboard on the \ key.

Answer (score -3):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to get #. Likewise should you ever need the Euro sign, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to get €.

Comment: No, on the British PC layout, # is over at the right edge of the keyboard. And € is at alt + 4, not alt + 2.